# Rounding floats with f-string

Tags: python, python-3.6

Using %-formatting, I can specify the number of decimal cases in a string:

```
x = 3.14159265
print('pi = %0.2f' %x)
```

This would give me:

```
pi = 3.14
```

Is there any way of doing this using f-strings in Python 3.6?

Comment: To be clear, you're only asking about round-to-nearest (like `%f` does), not round-down/truncate (like `int()`), round-up, round-towards-zero, round-towards-infinity or any other scheme? If only round-to-nearest, then this is a duplicate (cc: @vaultah)

Comment: But either way, this title *"Rounding floats with f-string"* and tagging [tag:python-3.6] is much better, clearer, wording, legible and better search keyword coverage  or duplicate than *"Convert floating point number to a certain precision, and then copy to string"*. So we should definitely leave this stand, closed but not deleted (cc: @vaultah)

Answer (score 310, accepted):

How about this

```
x = 3.14159265
print(f'pi = {x:.2f}')
```

[Docs for f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Comment: Is the `.2f` required? It seems to work with just `.2`.

Comment: @101 Yes, it is necessary. Using `.2` will not give you the expected value! It will round down to total of 2 digit using scientific notation and will only work on float numbers instead of ints as well